# What does `formData.append('files[]', file)` mean in API request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios, jquery-file-upload

I was refactoring [jQuery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

When jQuery file upload making a request(upload a jpg file), I've noticed this kind of payload in Chrome dev tools

[image]

view source

[image]

If I want to make the **same payload** as **jQuery file upload** did in **Axios**, I will have to do this:

```html
<input type="file" id="file-selector" />
```

```js
document.getElementById("file-selector").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  const formData = new window.FormData();

  formData.append("files[]", event.target.files[0]);

  axios.post(myEndPoint, formData);
});
```

The part I don't understand is `formData.append("files[]", event.target.files[0]);`

Why jQuery File Upload using the brackets `"files[]"` in formData key?

Or is my refactored Axios code got this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why jQuery File Upload using the brackets "files[]" in formData key?

As far as the client is concerned, the brackets are arbitrary parts of the name.

You could use `files[]` or `files{}` or `{}{}{}###!!!` or `bob` and it wouldn't make any difference to the client except for the `name=` part of the `Content-Disposition` header in the payload.

---

The *server* on the other hand **might** give special meaning to `[]`.

PHP, for example, will take the values from all the fields with the same name ending in `[]` and put them into an array. Given multiple fields with the same name that doesn't end in `[]` it will discard all but the last one.

Some other form processes libraries have adopted this convention. The Node.js [`body-parser` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) supports it as an optional feature with the `extended` parameter. It isn't universal though.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code has nothing specifically to do with jQuery:

```
formData.append("files[]", event.target.files[0]);
```

Breaking it down:

- `formData` is a reference to a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object. It is used to send binary file data in an AJAX request.
- The `append()` method is used to manually add content to the FormData object.
- `files[]` is the name of the request property to put the content in. The `[]` at the end of the key is, generally speaking, a PHP naming convention to instruct the server side to create an array from any content sent with the same key name.
- `event.target.files[0]` is the binary content which is being added to that key within the FormData object.

Answer (score 0):

That means, request parameter `files` is the array, rather than File object.

So, `formData.append("files[]", event.target.files[0]);` will allow you the upload one file.